# Meteor: Using collection sort with a variable object

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, meteor

I'm trying to sort a meteor collection that sorts based on menu options, with things like Newest ({createdAt: -1}), Oldest ({createdAt: 1}), etc.

and it works normally when I do:

```
Meteor.publish('listings', function listings() {
    return Listings.find({}, {sort: {createdAt: -1}});
})
```

However when I try to pass in a object variable called sorter, nothing gets returned:

```
sorter = {createdAt: -1}

Meteor.publish('listings', function listings(sort) {
    return Listings.find({}, {sort: sorter});
})
```

*However*, when I limit my sort of 15 items to lets say, 5, everything works completely fine!

```
Meteor.publish('listings', function listings(sort) {
    return Listings.find({}, {sort: sorter, limit: 5});
})
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated because I cannot find this answer anywhere!

Answer (score 0):

Nvm figured it out.

When I subscribed, I did:

```
const listingsSubcription = Meteor.subscribe('listings', props.input, props.sort);
```

But when I fetch it I also have to do:

```
listings: Listings.find({}, {sort: props.sort}).fetch(),
```